# VS2017 MSTEST Discovery Fails due to System.Runtime Binding in App.config

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, mstest

Whenever my [MSTEST](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/) projects have a `System.Runtime` binding under the `runtime` element in `app.config`, test discovery in the [Test Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer) fails. The Tests output in the Output Window looks like this:

```
[9/28/2017 12:37:17 PM Informational] ------ Discover test started ------
[9/28/2017 12:37:18 PM Warning] The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
[9/28/2017 12:37:18 PM Informational] ========== Discover test finished: 3 found (0:00:00.8953713) ==========
[9/28/2017 12:37:18 PM Informational] No tests found to run.
```

The `System.Runtime` binding looks like this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This binding is declared due to NuGet installs/updates.

Comment: There is a open issue on Github about it, unfortunately there is no solution for this issue. But have some workarounds about this issue, you can check if it works for you. https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/241.

Comment: The `dependentAssembly` tag in your app.config is not a reference, rather that is an assembly binding redirect.  The reference is in the csproj file.